# data is changed when inserting into database

Tags: php

I have a form contaning Full name, email, phone when inserting values into the database the phone number was change to 2147483647 (Full name and email are ok). Here are my PHP file
register.php

```
<h1>register form</h1>
<?php
$labels=array("full_name"=>"Full Name",
                "email"=>"Email",
                "phone"=>"Phone");
echo "<form action='check_register.php' method='POST'>";
foreach($labels as $key =>$value)
{
    echo "$value <input type='text' name='$key'/><br/>";
}
echo "<input type='submit' value='submit'/>";
echo "</form>";
?>
```

check_register.php

```
<?php
$labels=array("full_name"=>"Full Name",
                "email"=>"Email",
                "phone"=>"Phone");
foreach($_POST as $key =>$value)
{
    if(empty($value))
    {
        $empty_value[]=$key;
    }
    elseif($key=="full_name")
    {
        if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z '-]{2,50}$/",$value))
        {
            $invalid_value[]=$key;
        }
    }
    elseif($key=="email")
    {
        if(!preg_match("/^[A-Za-z0-9]{5,20}+(@)[A-Za-z0-9]{5,20}(\.com)$/",$value))
        {
            $invalid_value[]=$key;
        }
    }
    elseif($key=="phone")
    {   
        if(!preg_match("/^(\(\d+\)|\d+\-)?\d{10,20}$/",$value))
        {
            $invalid_value[]=$key;
        }
    }
}

if(@sizeof($empty_value)>0 or @sizeof($invalid_value)>0)
{
    if(@sizeof($empty_value)>0)
    {
        echo "input ";
        foreach($empty_value as $key) //loop empty value
        {
            echo " $labels[$key] ";
        }
    }
    if(@sizeof($invalid_value)>0)
    {
        echo "<br/>invalid data ";
        foreach($invalid_value as $key) //loop invalid_value
        {
            echo " $labels[$key]    ";
        }
    }
    echo "<form action='$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]' method='POST'>";
    foreach($labels as $key =>$value)
    {
        echo "$value <input type='text' name='$key'/><br/>";
    }
    echo "<input type='submit' value='submit'/>";
    echo "</form>";
    }
else
    {
    $user='root';
    $host='localhost';
    $password='root';
    $dbname='pet';
    $connect=mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password,$dbname) or die("can't connect to server");
        foreach($labels as $key =>$value)
        {
            $good_data[$key]=strip_tags(trim($_POST[$key]));
                if($key=="phone")
                {
                    $good_data[$key]=preg_replace("/[)( .-]/","",$good_data[$key]);
                }
            $good_data[$key]=mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,$good_data[$key]);
        }
        $query="INSERT INTO register ("; 
        foreach($good_data as $key =>$value)
        {
            $query.="$key,"; 
        }
        $query.= ") VALUES (";      
        $query=preg_replace("/,\)/",")",$query);
        foreach($good_data as $key =>$value)   
        {
            $query.="'$value',";
        }
        $query.=")";
        $query=preg_replace("/,\)/",")",$query);
        $query=preg_replace("/(\(\d+\)|\d+\-)/",")",$query);

        $result=mysqli_query($connect,$query) or die ("can't execute query.".mysqli_error($connect));
        echo "$query";
        echo "<h4>member inserted $query </h4>";
    }



?>
```

Comment: Change your datatype for the phone number field from an integer to a varchar

Comment: Phone number changes to `2147483647` no matter the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your phone number is stored as an `integer` and you are storing a number that is larger than an `integer` field.

Your options are to `alter` the table to make this field a `bigint` or a `varchar`.